# How to redirecting sysout and syserr to a custom Logger in java?

Tags: java, logging

I have a custom Logger and I want to redirect all the sysout and syserr from the console into that custom logger. So I am thinking to redirect sysout and syserr in the following way:

- By extending ByteArrayOutputStream
- And then to set System.setErr and System.setOut

  ```
  public class ServerLoggingPrintStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream  {
      public ServerLoggingPrintStream() {
          super();
      }

  public void write(byte[] originalBytes, int originalOffset, int originalLength) {
      synchronized(this) {
          String str = new String(originalBytes);
          if (str.length() == 0 || str.equals(System.getProperty("line.separator")) ) {
                      return;
          } 

          //using my custom logger named TRACE_LOGGER
          TRACE_LOGGER.log(LogLevel.INFO, this, "write", str);            
      }
    }
  }


  ServerLoggingPrintStream  serverLoggingPrintStreamStdOut_ = null;
  ServerLoggingPrintStream  serverLoggingPrintStreamStdErr_ = null;

  serverLoggingPrintStreamStdErr_ = new ServerLoggingPrintStream();
  System.setErr(new PrintStream(serverLoggingPrintStreamStdErr_));

  serverLoggingPrintStreamStdOut_ = new ServerLoggingPrintStream();
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(serverLoggingPrintStreamStdOut_));
  ```

Do you think is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: The better way is to avoid using System.err and System.out in the first place.

Comment: And an even better way is to use one of the many robust and proven logging frameworks available for Java rather than rolling your own. If you were to use `slf4j`, for example, there is a [plugin available](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j/).

Comment: the solution you are using is good enough.

Comment: There is already a logging framework in place. And this framework does not provide a way to redirect sysout and syserr. And at this moment I do not have the option to replace the existing logging framework.

Comment: What framework is it?

Comment: Its an internally written log framework and in place for a long time and at the moment do not have the option to get rid of it.

Comment: Could the following be of any help? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29

Comment: Hi Bram, I am already doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more complicated than that to get it right. That being said, there are open source projects that already do this, so you could borrow some code from there. One example is here:

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/logging/util/LoggerStream.java.html

Comment: Hi Yishai, what the situations that need to be handled?

Comment: @Baishakh, you can see the code at the link (or look for later versions of the class). One issue handled by the code is that PrintStream expects you to send your own new lines, logging frameworks generally do not, causing blank lines all over the place.

Comment: I can understand that. But what I do not understand why they need to use ThreadLocal recursiveCheck for that. We can just check whether we have a string and it is new line or empty line and we are done. right?

Comment: @Baishakh, the recursive check I imagine is defensive in case the registration code is called twice (so when you pass in the current System.out or System.err, you actually passing in this class). You would have to test out your implementation, but the advantage of using existing code from such a project is that it is well tested.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an OutputStream that redirects to the logging framework you use. Its fairly easy to implement (I assumed the charset to be ISO, so there is no fancy handling for encoding):

```
final class RedirectionOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(final int b) throws IOException {
        final char c = (char) (b & 0xFF);
        buffer.append(c);
        if (c == '\n') {
             // send buffered data to logging framework (its a complete line now)
             // reset buffer
             buffer.setLength(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Thats the gist of it, but the details may be different for your logging framework. The main problem is that loggers usually expect strings to log and you get raw, encoded bytes from the redirected stream, so you have to reverse the encoding (by raw cast in this example, technically this should be done using a Reader).

Comment: Hi, what is the advantage we are getting with this approach?

Comment: It works by implementing a stream to collect data until line feed, then forward that to the logger. The point is that it requires the least implementation (you already get properly working default implementations for all methods by inheriting from OutputStream directly). Its not *much* different from yours, only it covers the loopholes (there are 3 different write methods, you implemented only one).

Comment: How it is advantageous than the one I have proposed?